# Nowhere dense subset of unit square of measure $1$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

How can one construct or prove the existence of an example of a nowhere dense set in $[0,1]^2$ with Lebesgue measure $1$ using real analysis? Osgood gives an example in http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/osgood.pdf (also see pg 135 of http://www.kryakin.org/am2/_Olmsted.pdf) but I am not familiar with Jordan curves nor the technique being used. This is from an old qual, and I would like to know if it can be solved using real analysis.

If I cannot construct a set of measure 1, how can I construct a set of measure $1-\varepsilon$ if such sets exists?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: That has measure zero.

Comment: @PhoemueX Well color me shocked. Measure theory makes my head hurt.

Comment: There is no such set. If $A$ is nowhere dense, then the closure $\overline{A}$ has empty interior. In particular, the closure is a proper subset of the unit square, so that the complement $U := \overline{A}^c$ is nonempty. But $U$ is also open (as a subset of the unit square) and it is easy to see that a nonempty open subset of the unit square has positive measure. Hence, $0<\mu(U)=1-\mu(\overline{A}) \leq 1-\mu(A)$, i.e. $\mu(A)<1$.

Comment: @PhoemueX can I make sets of measure less than 1 but arbitrarily close to 1?

Comment: Yes, you can. Since $N := \Bbb{Q}^2 \cap [0,1]^2$ is a null set, by regularity, we find for each $\epsilon >0$ an open set $U \supset N$ with $\mu(U)<\epsilon$. Now $A := U^c$ is closed and has nonempty interior, since it would otherwise contain a point of $N$. Hence, $A$ is nowhere dense, but has $\mu(A)>1-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of fat Cantor sets (you might google "Smith-Volterra-Cantor set") shows us how to build a closed subset of $[0,1]$ with empty interior whose measure is arbitrarily close to $1$. Taking a union of a sequence of Cantor sets whose measures approach $1$, we get (by the Baire category theorem) a set with empty interior of full measure. But this set is not nowhere dense; in fact it will be dense.

Everything I said here extends straightforwardly to higher dimensions.

Comment: is your union contained in $[0,1]$ or does each Cantor set you described lie on a different horizontal line in the square?

Comment: @cap You should divide up the square in a grid, similar to how the construction of the Cantor set divides the interval into subintervals.

Comment: can you provide a link? The only example i can find is one with measure 1/2 and i don't see how this number is related to how they remove the intervals.

Comment: @cap The key is how big the intervals removed at each step are. In the classic ternary Cantor set, you remove a third of each of the previous $2^n$ intervals. This cuts out a third of the measure of what is already there, so it multiplies the measure by $2/3$, which will go to zero. In the classic Smith-Volterra-Cantor set, you remove a $2^{2n+2}$th (so a fourth, then a sixteenth, then ....) from each of the previous intervals. There are $2^n$ of them, so in each step you cut out $\frac{2^n}{2^{2n+2}}$ worth of measure, which adds up to $1/2$.

Comment: @cap You can instead remove more or less and get a different positive measure. For instance if you remove $\frac{2^n}{2^{2n+m}}$ ($m \geq 1$), the resulting measure removed will be $2^{1-m}$.